# python pandas parse date without delimiters 'time data '060116' does not match format '%dd%mm%YY' (match)'

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas, time-series

I am trying to parse a date column that looks like the one below,

```
date
061116
061216
061316
061416
```

However I cannot get pandas to accept the date format as there is no delimiter (eg '/'). I have tried this below but receive the error:

> ValueError: time data '060116' does not match format '%dd%mm%YY' (match)

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%dd%mm%YY')
```

Comment: You sure you don't have everything backwards? It looks like month-day not day-month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add parameter `errors='coerce'` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), because `13` and `14` months does not exist, so this dates are converted to `NaT`:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d%m%y', errors='coerce'))
0   2016-11-06
1   2016-12-06
2          NaT
3          NaT
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or maybe you need swap months with days:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m%d%y'))

0   2016-06-11
1   2016-06-12
2   2016-06-13
3   2016-06-14
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
         Date
0  0611160130
1  0612160130
2  0613160130
3  0614160130

print (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m%d%y%H%M', errors='coerce'))
0   2016-06-11 01:30:00
1   2016-06-12 01:30:00
2   2016-06-13 01:30:00
3   2016-06-14 01:30:00
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

[Python's strftime directives](http://strftime.org/).

Comment: Glad can help you!

Comment: I will accept the answer once it lets me. If I where to want to parse a similar time for instance 0130 aka 1:30 would '%h%m' work for me?

Comment: I add solution to my answer.

Comment: Great thank you, just so I understand that format is how pandas interprets the format you give them, it does not define the output

Comment: Thank you for accepting. I also add link to the bottom of answer, it is really helpful if need parse dates. Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Your date format is wrong. You have days and months reversed. It should be:

```
 %m%d%Y
```